# How do I get output using jq in the way it gives me the whole line where a word or string came in

Tags: grep, jq

My question is somewhat similar to it but still allow me to elaborate. I have been accessing a weather application called wttr.in from where I can get weather information. This can be easily called by -

```
$ curl wttr.in/Pune?format=4
```

Now what I am interested to know if the weather station is giving current data or stale data for which I came to know something called j1 format which gives the last time the server updated the weather info.

```
$ curl wttr.in/Pune?format=j1 | less
```

The above query gives me a ton of data, something like -

```
current_condition": [
        {
            "FeelsLikeC": "18",
            "FeelsLikeF": "65",
            "cloudcover": "4",
            "humidity": "42",
            "localObsDateTime": "2021-11-11 12:20 AM",
            "observation_time": "06:50 PM",
            "precipInches": "0.0",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "pressure": "1012",
            "pressureInches": "30",
            "temp_C": "18",
```

Now if I use grep I get the output like this -

```
$ curl wttr.in/Pune?format=j1 | grep "localObsDateTime"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  2 48685    2  1159    0     0   4199      0  0:00:11 --:--:--  0:00:11  4184            "localObsDateTime": "2021-11-11 12:20 AM",
100 48685  100 48685    0     0  90830      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 90661
```

I have heard that jq could prettify it and makt ie easy, can anybody tell me how. Also, instead of curl if there is any other way to get data out would also be interesting.

FWIW I have installed ja 1.6 and bash version at my end is 5.1.8.

Comment: This might help: [Parse JSON data using jq and curl from command line](https://medium.com/how-tos-for-coders/https-medium-com-how-tos-for-coders-parse-json-data-using-jq-and-curl-from-command-line-5aa8a05cd79b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
curl wttr.in/Pune?format=j1 | jq '.current_condition[].localObsDateTime'
```

Answer (score 4):

With `jq`:

```
curl -s 'http://wttr.in/Pune?format=j1' | jq -r '.current_condition[].localObsDateTime'
```

Output:

```
2021-11-11 03:01 AM
```

Comment: Both seem same, except for the -r flag which I have no clue what it means/represents hence giving the selected answer to the one who answered correctly and quickly first, sorry.

Comment: @shirish The `-r` option makes `jq` return a decoded string. Without the `-r`, you get a JSON-encoded string back (this is trivial to test and to check in the `jq` manual). Furthermore, this answer correctly quotes the URL (without quoting, you'd get an error in some shells, depending on the shell's configuration, since this URL is also a globbing pattern).  It also does away with `curl`'s status output. If you like correct answers, this one is (currently) "more correct". Note that other users may come along later and provide even better answers. Being first is no real guarantee of anything.

Comment: @shirish: Both of this "minor" additions (`-r` and `-s`) are really important, and I recommend using both of them. This is not related to the original question about `jq`, but still: better use the https endpoint in the query

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know exactly where in the JSON document the `localObsDateTime` key is located, you will have to search for it recursively.  You can do that, and then extract its value, with the following `jq` expression:

```
.. | select(type == "object" and has("localObsDateTime")).localObsDateTime
```

This essentially says "for each individual thing in the document, if it's an object and has a key called `localObsDateTime`, then extract that key's value".

You could also shorten it into

```
.. | .localObsDateTime? // empty
```

which says "for each individual thing in the document, try extracting the `localObsDateTime` value, if it exists, and if it doesn't or its value is `null`, just give me nothing".

You would run this like so:

```bsh
$ curl -s 'http://wttr.in/Pune?format=j2' |
    jq -r '.. | select(type == "object" and has("localObsDateTime")).localObsDateTime'
2021-11-17 12:16 AM
```

or,

```bsh
$ curl -s 'http://wttr.in/Pune?format=j2' |
    jq -r '.. | .localObsDateTime? // empty'
2021-11-17 12:16 AM
```

The `-r` option to `jq` makes the utility return a decoded text string rather than a JSON string.

Note that the above returns the values of *all* `localObsDateTime` keys.  Would you only want the first of these, use the following `jq` expression instead:

```
[ .. | select(type == "object" and has("localObsDateTime")).localObsDateTime ][0]
```

or,

```
[ .. | .localObsDateTime? // empty ][0]
```

This creates an array of all the values and then extracts the first.

Note that using `j2` in place of `j1` in the URL causes the JSON document in the reply to be smaller.

Comment: Very good and useful answer. Sort of `jq`-style `grep`. It is a pity that `jq` does not have some shortcut for this very important query

Comment: @IgorChubin It has, `jq -r '.. | .localObsDateTime? // empty'`.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I missed it. Very cool

Comment: @IgorChubin No worries! Your comment got me revisiting the issue and I realized there was a shorter way of writing it, so I updated the answer. Thanks!